# Calc won't fit any curve to any data, complains “Model expression is too complex”

Tags: calc

Even if I copy the example from here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Linear-Fits.html#Linear-Fits this one:

```
[ [ 1, 2, 3, 4,  5  ]
  [ 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 ] ]
```

to be more specific, and then press <kbd>a F 1 RET</kbd>, all I get is the error message "Model expression is too complex: a + b * x". Do I have to do something special to make it work? Calc can plot data, so that's not an issue.

Running `emacs -Q` gives the same result.

<sub>Emacs Version: `GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.8.2) of 2013-08-14 on buildvm-15.phx2.fedoraproject.org`</sub>

Comment: What Emacs version are you running? The example works fine here (Emacs v24.3.1, Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm having exactly the same issue, anything I try to fit gives me the same complaint. I stumbled across [this](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-02/msg00161.html) though, which just says it's a bug in 24.3 and fixed in 24.4.

Comment: Yes, that must be it. Just tried it with a newer version (`GNU Emacs 24.4.50 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.6.4)`), and got the expected result.